# Translation of "many ways to ..."

Tags: traduction

"There are many ways to live a happy life."

How to translate this sentence? I think *chemin* or *voie* would not be the right translation of "way" here, so I'd use *façon* or *manière*. Would this be a good translation?

> Il y a plusieurs façons/manières dont on peut vivre une vie heureuse.

I'm also not sure if I should use "dont" or "dans lesquelles".

Comment: You are right, and Bkyn is spot on :) *Il y a plusieurs façons **de** faire quelque chose.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Il y a plusieurs façons/manières **de** vivre une vie heureuse.

Both "façons/manières" are correct but "dont" or "dans lesquelles" wouldn't work here.